# How to put a function as a new variable

Tags: r, function, variables

`Create a new variable **normal_z**=$\Phi^{-1}(\frac{i-0.5}{2000}), i=1,2,\cdots,2000$, where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile/inverse function of a standard normal distribution.`

When I try to create this variable in R it always comes up with an error code--that is, I have been copying the whole function and putting it with normal_z <- but that doesn't work. I have also tried normal_z <- function($\Phi^{-1}(\frac{i-0.5}{2000}), i=1,2,\cdots,2000$,) and that does not work either. I tried taking away the i=1,2.... part and that doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that you have the definition of your function in latex and try to directly use this latex as R code. This does not work because R has a different syntax than latex. For a start, have a look [how the quantile function for the normal distribution is used](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Normal)

Comment: I'm guessing that you are reading a homework problem that was composed in Tex but failed to be properly rendered before it was distributed.